# What is relationship between Page.IsValid and args.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is Page.IsValid and args.IsValid depend each on other?

I mean if args.IsValid="true" the Page.IsValid must be "true".

And ofcourse conversely: 
if Page.IsValid="true" so args.IsValid="true"

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the methods to see what they actually do?

Comment: Take a look at [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or [JustDecompile](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Fproducts%2Fdecompiler.aspx&ei=5hAqT7j2O6ersAKQ7IyNDg&usg=AFQjCNGS8oaJtbgxshAC-2iBxQRs-igL0g). Point either one of them at one of your .NET DLL's and you'll be able to see the C# source code that represents how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.IsValid` (readonly) returns true when page validation succeeded; otherwise, false.

Read [MSDN doc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx)

> For this property to return true, all validation server controls in
>   the current validation group must validate successfully. You should
>   check this property only after you have called the Page.Validate
>   method, or set the CausesValidation property to true in the
>   OnServerClick event handler for an ASP.NET server control that
>   initiates form processing.

In `ServerValidation` handler; You may set `true` or `false` to `ServerValidateEventArgument.IsValid` property if input validation (args.Value) is succeed or failed respectively.

[MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs.isvalid.aspx)

> Once your validation routine finishes, use the IsValid property to
>   indicate whether the value specified by the Value property passed
>   validation. This value determines whether the input control associated
>   with the CustomValidator control passed validation.

Answer (score 2):

Both are quiet different in implementation Page.IsValid applied for page and args.isValid is for Custom Validation purpose see the example below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>CustomValidator ServerValidate Example</title>
<script runat="server">

      void ValidateBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 

         // Display whether the page passed validation.
         if (Page.IsValid) 
         {

            Message.Text = "Page is valid.";

         }

         else 
         {

            Message.Text = "Page is not valid!";

         }

      }

      void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
      {

         try 
         {

            // Test whether the value entered into the text box is even.
            int i = int.Parse(args.Value);
            args.IsValid = ((i%2) == 0);

         }

         catch(Exception ex)
         {

            args.IsValid = false;

         }

      }

   </script>    

</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <h3>CustomValidator ServerValidate Example</h3>

      <asp:Label id="Message"  
           Text="Enter an even number:" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="10pt" 
           runat="server"
           AssociatedControlID="Text1"/>

      <br />

      <asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
           runat="server" />

      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
           ControlToValidate="Text1"
           Display="Static"
           ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"
           ForeColor="green"
           Font-Names="verdana" 
           Font-Size="10pt"
           OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
           runat="server"/>

      <br />

      <asp:Button id="Button1"
           Text="Validate" 
           OnClick="ValidateBtn_OnClick" 
           runat="server"/>

   </form>

</body>
</html>
```