# Page.IsValid and IsValid Property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET. just want to ask when we check if any validation fails, we do:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
   ...
}
```

can we do:

```
if (IsValid)
{
...
}
```

are they the same?

Comment: Have you checked out these SO posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9107227/718373) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763706/718373) on the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is relationship between Page.IsValid and args.IsValid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106836/what-is-relationship-between-page-isvalid-and-args-isvalid)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, i.e. where the code is.

Whenever you call a property without specifying the object it belongs to, `this` is implied. So for example, this:

```
if (IsValid)
```

...is the same as this:

```
if (this.IsValid)
```

If the code exists within a page, then you `this.IsValid` is calling the `IsValid` property of the current page object. Which would make it the same.

Comment: I do like `public partial class myForm : System.Web.UI.Page`, so they are the same, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It inherits from `Page`, so `myForm` is a subclass of or is a type of `Page`, having all of its methods and properties.

Comment: so when we have to use  `Page.IsValid`, could you give me a code example? thanks

Comment: A code example wouldn't tell you much because it's all about the context. You'd have to use it whenever `this` and `Page` are different, e.g. any code that is not running within the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you also have a look at this question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860715/how-servervalidateeventargs-works-in-asp-net